# How to read mail using terminal?

Tags: linux, smtp, mailx

I've set up my my smtp server using ssmtp which I set up as default. So now I can send emails using `mail` and I'm receiving them(checked on my phone), but I can't read them using `mail`, or by `cat /var/mail/myuser` or  by `cat /var/spool/myuser`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your phone connecting to in order to read your email?

Comment: My phone is connecting to my email address via gmail application

Comment: If your email is on Gmail why do you expect to read it with `cat` from a file on your local computer?

Comment: I've used ssmtp to use my email and I've configured it like in [here](https://tecadmin.net/send-email-smtp-server-linux-command-line-ssmtp/) and I can send mails using 'mail' command. So I guessed I could. Is it possible though, am I missing something, or It's just impossible and I can only send mails but not read them?

Comment: So you probably want to install a program, not dissimilar to your `gmail application`, that connects to gmail, gets your email and stores it on your local machine. `fetchmail` used to be popular, there is http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/ and many others.

Comment: `mutt` or the `pine` reimplementation might work for you.

Comment: Okay. And now considering I did this at work, if I send a mail on local network using `mail` command, will I send it using my gmail account that I set up with `ssmtp`, or with my account that I'm logged with to the netwwork? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Install `mutt` MUA. It's powerfull and can help you.